# problem when printing from web service

Tags: .net, printing, service

I have an application that needs to be able to print in different printers. This application has a desktop interface and a web service. If I try to print from the desktop application there is no problem, I'm able to print in both local and network printers, the problem is when I try to print via web service in a network printer (local printers works fine), I'm having the following error "RPC server unavailable"

I did a lot of research but still can't find the solution to this problem, hope someone knows how to solve it

thanks in advance for you help...

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked your permissions? Try to change your application pool account in IIS to SYSTEM or an administrative account. If printing is now possible from your Web Service, you can dig deeper into permissions and which are needed.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm working with IIS 5.1. Where can I change the application pool account?